# How to preserve quotes of string during .format

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a multi-line file, lines like:

```
workspace -fr "fluidCache" "cache/nCache/fluid";
```

On some of the lines I need to use a variable containing a file path, when I use the following:

```
render_output = os.path.join(project_root, r'common\render_output')
ws_file.write("""workspace -fr "images" {0};""".format(render_output))
```

result:

```
workspace -fr "images" I:\..\common\render_output;
```

The result I need is render_output with quotes:

```
workspace -fr "images" "I:\..\common\render_output";
```

How might I format the render_output  so that the quotations of its string value are maintained in the triple quoted write argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ws_file.write("""workspace -fr "images" "{0}";""".format(render_output))
```

Comment: wow, that was fast, I can't even mark it as answered yet. I'm kind of embarrassed its that simple. Thanks gilch!